# What do you call a polynomial of degree $n$ that satisfies $x^nP(1/x)=P(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a polynomial $P(x)=c_0+c_1x+\cdots c_nx^n$ has symmetric coefficients, $c_{n-k}=c_k$, then it satisfies $x^nP(1/x)=P(x)$.

For example, if $P(x)=1+3x+x^2$ then $P(1/x)=1+3/x+1/x^2$, so $x^2P(1/x)=P(x)$.

Does this property have a name?

Comment: I've heard "palindromic" but I wouldn't call that usage universal.  There's also ["self-reciprocal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) but that just seems wrong to me.

Comment: This term "self-reciprocal" doesn't hurt me...